# Есть ли кеширование запросов в IIS?

Tags: php, laravel, iis, кэширование

Можно ли IIS настроить так, чтобы, например, один и тот же запрос кешировался минут на 10 и пользователю возвращался сохраненный HTML вместо нового обращения к PHP (или другим интерпретаторам)?

Если ответ да, то что будет, если по одному и тому же URL должны выводиться разные данные (HTTP аутентификация / куки / сессия)?

Подробное описание проблемы:
Связка IIS (внутрикорпоративный сервер на винде 4 ядра Xeони on 2.67 Ghz + 6gb озу) + PHP Fast-CGI. Вебсайт на laravel. Проблема: если 100-150 человек одновременно заходят на сайт, все виснет. Заметил, что уже при ab -c 10 загрузка CPU становится 100%. Решил это исправить. Поставил opcache. Запросы с базы само собой кешируются. Вот смотрю, как бы еще закешировать.

Comment: опишите всю картину целиком. Что хотите кэшировать и почему. Какие фреймворки и т.п. используются в приложении

Comment: @teran Связка IIS (внутрикорпоративный сервер на винде 4 ядра Xeon 2.67 Ghz + 6gb озу) + PHP Fast-CGI.
Вебсайт на laravel. Проблема: если 100-150 человек одновременно заходят на сайт, все виснет.
Заметил, что уже при ab -c 10 загрузка CPU становится 100%. Решил это исправить.
Поставил opcache. Запросы с базы само собой кешируются. Вот смотрю, как бы еще закешировать.

Comment: вышеперечисленное лучше внести в текст вопроса, и добавить тэг [tag:laravel]. `wincache` еще попробуйте добавить помимо `opcache`

Comment: СУБД на том же сервере расположена или на отдельном?

Comment: @teran СУБД на отдельном сервере. Наоборот 100 загрузка возникает когда выполняешь легкие запросы без обращения к бд. Xdebug показал что лара грузит аутолоадом порядка 300 файлов . А wincache и opcache вместе можно ?

Comment: Простите, тупанул с `wincache`, вместо, конечно, а не вместе :) По крайней мере [тут](http://php.net/manual/ru/install.windows.recommended.php) рекомендуют wincache использовать на iis